# Aplicación React Native al intentar generar .apk release no funciona

Tags: android, react-native

Tengo varios proyectos creados con react-native hace 1 día podía generar bien el .apk, pero ahora ejecuto el comando termina sin dar errores pero no se encuentra el fichero /android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk, probé en varios y pasa igual no genera el .apk

Esto es la respuesta al usar el comando:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No entiendo bien qué te sucede, el log te dice que hizo el build correctamente, cual es el problema?

Comment: @GermanAlzate el problema es que no genera o crea el fichero .apk

Answer (score 0):

Respondo la pregunta pues quizá le pueda ser útil a alguien que le pase lo mismo, en realidad el error fue mio, usando la guía https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android (que en este momento hace referencia a la version 60-RC si no se cambia) para generar mi .apk release, como ya previamente había hecho todos los pasos pues había generado el .apk antes solo fui a la parte de la guía donde esta el comando para generar y copie "./gradlew bundleRelease" sin fijarme que lo que genera es un fichero AAB y se encontraría acá android/app/build/outputs/bundle/release/app.aab . En realidad debia usar el comando "./gradlew assembleRelease" que si genera el .apk o bueno usar el app.aab